# I'd like to use sed to insert text above a string, if it doesn't already exist in the file

Tags: sed

Specifically, I'm trying to add:

```
define('VHP_VARNISH_IP','1.2.3.4');
```

above the string:

```
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

inside of all "wp-config.php" files if the string doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 1):

This would be painful to quote on the command line, so I suggest you put the following code

```
:a
$!{
  N
  ba
}
/define('VHP_VARNISH_IP','1\.2\.3\.4');/ !{
  s#/\* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging\. \*/#define('VHP_VARNISH_IP','1.2.3.4');\n&#
}
```

into a file, say `foo.sed`, and run `sed -f foo.sed filename`.

The code works as follows: The

```
:a     # loop label
$!{    # if the end of the input was not yet reached
  N    # fetch the next line
  ba   # go back to a
}
```

bit reads the whole file into the pattern space. Then,

```
/define('VHP_VARNISH_IP','1\.2\.3\.4');/ !{
```

checks if `define('VHP_VARNISH_IP','1.2.3.4');` is part of the pattern space, and if that is not the case

```
  s#/\* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging\. \*/#define('VHP_VARNISH_IP','1.2.3.4');\n&#
```

substitutes `/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */` with `define('VHP_VARNISH_IP','1.2.3.4');\n` followed by the just-matched token (the `That's all` line).

Note that this will only work if the `That's all` line exists in the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to avoid adding the string if it appears directly before your target location, and if you're not worried about cases where your target occurs multiple times in the file and may already have the string present in some places, it is sufficient to do:

```
sed "\@$REPL@q; \@$STRING@i\\
$REPL
" input
```

But, in your case you need to escape the special characters in STRING.
For example:

```
$ cat input
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
$ STRING="/\* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. \*/"
$ REPL="define('VHP_VARNISH_IP','1.2.3.4');"
$ sed "\@$REPL@q; \@$STRING@i\\
$REPL
" input
define('VHP_VARNISH_IP','1.2.3.4');
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

If those restrictions are too strict, simply replace `q` with `{N; n;}`